# PostgreSQL 13.2 on Windows won't accept passwords and editing pg_hba.conf doesn't work

Tags: postgresql

I installed PostgreSQL 13.2 on Windows. The service is running, but when I use `psql -Upostgres` to connect it always fails password authentication even though I am entering the right password. I read that if you set the METHOD to trust in pg_hba.conf then it shouldn't even ask for passwords. I did that and then restarted the service--it still asks for the password and fails.

I've run out of ideas on what to try, so I thought I'd try here. Any thoughts?

Comment: Look in the server's log file for the detailed message on why it failed.

Comment: @jjanes The log file doesn't contain anything after `database system is ready to accept connections`

Comment: Got it! See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that a docker container was running that was using port 5432 so postgres was using port 5433. I had thought that the docker container was stopped, so I had put it completely out of my mind. When I used `psql` without specifying a port, it was attempting to connect to the db running in the docker container, which had a different password for the user `postgres`. (This also explained why changing `METHOD` to `trust` in pg_hba.conf didn't work: it was the wrong instance of postgres that I was connecting to.)